# What sufficient and necessary conditions should a square matrix have if it has an inverse and its inverse is non-negative?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What sufficient and necessary conditions should a square matrix $\mathbf{A}$ have if it has an inverse and its inverse is non-negative?

Comment: what do you mean by non-negative?

Comment: @WillJagy That means each element of this matrix is greater than or equal to 0

Comment: Try with $2\times 2$ matrix and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Call the $n \times n$ matrix $A$. By "non-negative" let's assume you mean that every entry is non-negative.Write $A_{ij}=(-1)^{i+j}$determinant of matrix formed by removing row $i$ and column $j$ from $A$. Two conditions:(i) $\det(A)\ne 0$ and (ii)$\frac{A_{ij}}{\det(A)}\ge0$ for all $1\le i,j\le n$

Comment: I think $\det (A) \neq 0$ is redundant since it is implied by the existence of the inverse.